Implementation of probabilistic social choice functions?
It is well-known that Maskin (1999) provided an almost complete characterisation of implementable social choice rules in Nash equilibrium strategies. According to his result, monotonicity is a necessary condition for Nash implementation; and with three players and the no-veto power condition, it is also sufficient.
However, Maskin’s (1999) results apply only to social choice rules (i.e, functions from preference profiles to outcome sets). I have been looking for papers that deal with the implementation of probabilistic social choice functions (i.e., functions from preference profiles to lotteries over the set of outcomes), hoping to find an analogous result to Maskin’s (1999) for probabilistic social choice functions.
Unfortunately, I have found no such paper. I suspect that the sort of characterisation result I am looking for is either trivial or too difficult to obtain.
Hence, my question: can you please direct me to any paper that deals with the implementation of probabilistic social choice functions?
